# Stanford NLP: Retrieving the updated annotation for action in SequenceMatchRules

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using the Sequence Match Rules as part of TokenRegex in the Stanfords CoreNLP library and having some issues retrieving an updated annotation based upon the evaluation of the action in the match rules.

```
rule = { type: "CLASS" , value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TokensAnnotation" 

{  
   "ruleType":"tokens",
   "pattern": ( /This/ /should/ /match/ ) ,
   "action": (  Annotate($0, rule, "RetrieveThisValue" ) ),
   "result":"This is the result"
}
```

How do I retrieve the value `"RetrieveThisValue"` from the annotated coremap. According to the docs [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/tokensregex/types/Expressions.html) I would have thought I could retrieve the value from the matched expression CoreMap. When I use something like `matchedexpression.get(0).getAnnotation().get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).toString()` I get the results field "This is the result" and I do not get the "RetrieveThisValue" as well.

I can find the "RetrieveThisValue" deep in the extract function of the MatchedExpression.

How do I retrieve "RetrieveThisValue" upon matching an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules file: this-should-match.rules

```
ruleClass = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$GoldAnswerAnnotation" }

{
   "pattern": ( /This/ /should/ /match/ ),
   "action": ( Annotate($0, ruleClass, "this should match!") ),
   "result": "This is the result!"
}
```

Code:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.util.*;


public class TokensRegexExampleTwo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // set up properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,tokensregex");
    props.setProperty("tokensregex.rules", "this-should-match.rules");
    props.setProperty("tokensregex.caseInsensitive", "true");

    // set up pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // set up text to annotate
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("This should match.");

    // annotate text
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);

    // print out found entities
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        System.out.println(token.word() + "\t" +
            token.get(edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.GoldAnswerAnnotation.class));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: I don't think you should use the GoldAnswer annotation, you should probably make up a brand new annotation class to handle your use case.  But I was just using that as an example.

Comment: Thank you. I will review and if sufficient reward with the answer.